# Connecting to remote MSMQ

Tags: msmq

I'm writing my first application using MSMQ and everything works well with local queues on my development machine. I cannot seem to connect to a remote queue when I tested it.

I have 10 Windows 10 Pro installation (not domain joined, but I have also tried this on two domain joined machines), both with MSMQ installed. I have disabled the firewall on both machines, unchecked the 'Disable un-authenticated RPC calls" on both machines. Changed the permissions on the queue to full control for everyone and anonymous.

I'm using .NET and the system.messaging namespace. When I call the messagequeue constructor, I can see that most of the properties are in a exception state.

VB code New MessageQueue("FormatName:Direct=TCP:x.x.x.x\private$\test")

I found an article detailing a registry entry NewRemoteReadServerAllowNoneSecurityClient I thought might work but got the same result. I'm sure this is some sort of security issue but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Anyone have any ideas? Seems like this should be much easier than I am experiencing.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: That's the weird part. The constructor itself doesn't generate an exception. After a initiating the object I inspect it and some of the properties say there was an exception, but not all.  The authenticate and base priority propteries (and others) say msmg.Authenticate there an exception of type system.messaging.messagequeueexception. when I tried this originally on a domain joined machine to a non domain machine I was able to drill into the ResultView collection and discovered a access to message queue denied error.